# Play protect Warning Pop-Up While installing Android app

Tags: android, installation, google-play-protect

So we have an app that's deployed via the Microsoft AppCenter and one of the users received the following pop-up when trying to install it.

[Play Protect Pop Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pw4N.png)

Couldn't find any particular resource when I googled it except for the Minimum Target APK Version policy.
The app in question has a minSdkVersion="21" and compile version(Target Framework) = Android 8.1 (27)

Would be super grateful if anybody can help me out with this.

Comment: The minimum target version of the app is what is causing the dialog, the required minimum goes up every year and is now up to 29

Comment: Thanks @tyczj . We tried the same on phones having Android 11 and 10 and we could not reproduce this. Is there something that we're overlooking?